# How to propagate updates to Parent entity(Table) when child is updated

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Please help me out here.

I have Parent to child relationship (One to Many) and In this case, the parent table is holding few records of the entity and other related attributes are in the child table.

When a child record is updated the requirement is to update the parent table also because they are related.

Like Person to Additional Personal details (when personal details are updated, we need to update the Person object table also to let the user know that the whole entity is changed.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your entities mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Load the child object by loading root entity. Then save root entity to update parent and also child.